# Translate “Imagine if…”

Tags: grammar

Is there an idiomatic way to translate a phrase that begins with “imagine if…”? Ie, a phrase to introduce an imagined possibility. Something like:

> Imagine if I won the lottery. I could buy a house!

I get the impression that “se” is more strictly logical than “if” in English. So if I translated it word-for-word as “imagu se mi gajnus la loterion”, it would have a weird meaning that I want you to imagine something but only if I won the lottery. Is that correct?

Would it be understandable to translate it like:

> Imagu ke mi gajnus la loterion. Mi povus aĉeti domon!

Answer (score 4):

Mi kontrolis en la [Tekstaro](https://tekstaro.com/). Se mi serĉas [`imagu,? ke\b`](https://tekstaro.com/?s=5dfe385e65aac) estas 84 rezultoj, do ŝajnas ke ĝi estas uzata esprimo.

Alikflanke se mi serĉas [`imagu,? se\b`](https://tekstaro.com/?s=5dfe38c3b6966), aperas 15 rezultoj. Ili ja ŝajnas kiel uzoj por prezenti imagaton eblon. Ekzemple:

El Monato:

> Imagu, se mi elparolus tiujn nomojn laŭ la direktivoj en MONATO

El La Granda Aventuro, Ferenc Szilágyi, 1931-1945:

> Imagu, se ni povus havigi ankoraŭ dudek kilogramojn!

Do, ŝajnas al mi ke la frazo ja estas uzata. Eble oni povas pardoni la nelogikon se oni imagus ĝin kiel “imagu [tion kio okazus] se…”.

Tamen pro la plia ofteco de “imagu, ke”, eble tiu lasta estas pli bona.

Comment: Ĉu vi povus redakti pro havigi ligon al la serĉoj en la Tekstaro?

Comment: @Trey Mi provis krei la ligilojn sed mi ŝajne trovis cimon en la Tekstaro. La ligilo aldonas duan “\” kaj la serĉo ne funkcias. Mi sendis mesaĝon al Bertilo por raporti ĝin.

Comment: Dankon; kiam vi havas ligon, bonvolu aldoni ĝin?

Comment: @Trey Bertilo riparis la cimon kaj la ligiloj nun funkcias 

Comment: Ho, mojose! Dankon pro tio!

Answer (score 1):

I think you're right. While there is no doubt about

> Se mi gajnus la loterion...

it might be ambiguous with *imagu*.

So I think

> Imagu ke mi gajnus la loterion.

is much better. I'm not totally sure if it is correct in English to say *Imagine that I would...*. In German it's perfectly fine to say *Stell dir vor, dass...* and I think it's fine and understandable in Esperanto.

Answer (score 1):

In the book Complete Esperanto (by Tim Owen and Judith Meyer) appears [the following sentence](https://books.google.es/books?id=N_9GDwAAQBAJ&lpg=PT249&dq=%22Imagine%20if%22%20%22imagu%20se%22&hl=es&pg=PT249#v=onepage&q=%22Imagine%20if%22%20%22imagu%20se%22&f=false) (in Esperanto and English):

> Imagu, se oni farus tiel al katidoj aŭ al hundidoj!
>
> Imagine if it were like that with kittens and puppies!

If that is the sense you are trying to convey, then it seems that your sentence (*imagu se mi gajnus la loterion*) is OK, maybe with a comma after *imagu*.

Answer (score 1):

### How about *(ni) supozu ke*?

I’m going to take a different route than other responders. Searching [*La Tekstaro,*](https://tekstaro.com/) it appears to me that changing words — from *imagu* to *supozu* — may idiomatically be the best choice to capture the connotations of “imagine if” you posit.

First, I just searched for *imagu* vs. *supozu.* Two things jump out immediately from the results:

1. *imagu* is used mostly in direct quotation, while *supozu* is more-often used in the main text.
2. *imagu* does, as your question points out, take either *se* or *ke,* with different connotations. But *supozu* seems to, almost always, use *ke.*

Then I compared two more-targeted searches. (If you don’t know regular expressions, I explain them below this answer.)

First, [`imagu\W?\s+[sk]e`](https://tekstaro.com/?s=5e07cd2496821). Indeed, it appears frequently in direct quotations and only a few times in the first 100 results in the main text. As said, the usage of *se* and *ke* varies.

Finally, *ne imagu* occurs rather frequently—without always having the idiomatic meaning “don’t imagine…” has in English of being a mild or veiled threat (e.g., “don’t imagine you can continue to displease me”)—frequently, it is literally used as a negative imperative phrase.

On the other hand, a search for [`supozu\W?\s+[sk]e`](https://tekstaro.com/?s=5e07cc6470fa9), returns *ke* vastly more often than *se* (you won’t even find *supozu se* in the linked search, you’ll have to expand the parameters to find it). Also, a large proportion of the results are in the main prose.

If you spot-check the results (you can tap the underlined matches to get a full paragraph’s context for each), it seems like the connotations of *supozu ke* is more along the lines of what you’re getting at—introducing and positing a hypothetical future for further consideration, rather than exhorting an expansion of the interlocutor’s mind (like, say, in John Lennon’s “Imagine”).

So while this isn’t a case of “false friends”, it does seem to me to be a case where the cognate isn’t the best choice since *imagu* supports much finer grains of subtlety. *Supozu ke,* however, seems to nearly always mean basically what you’re going for.

The one drawback, I think, is that if you’re talking about something like winning the lottery, *Supozu!* as an intensifying interjection doesn’t really work as *Imagu!* does.

I’d also note that the indirect first-person imperative *ni supozu ke…* (“let’s suppose that…”) seems to be as common, or nearly, as the second-person imperative *supozu ke*. As a main-prose introducer, both forms are semantically near-identical, as they are in English:

- **Suppose that** the moon were made of green cheese…
- **Let’s suppose** the moon were made of green cheese…

Writers differ in Esperanto, just as in English, on whether to use the first-person plural (“we” or *ni*) or the second person (“you” or *vi*, but usually—in both languages—just unstated) in such contexts.

They generally read the same, though I think in educational contexts (textbooks, explanatory essays, and so on) the first-person plural “let’s” is more frequently encountered, since the writer is trying to imply an active involvement by the reader. In *La Tekstaro* there seem to be many more attestations of *ni supozu* in early Esperanto history and more of *(vi) supozu* in more recent Esperanto.

---

#### p.s.: Regexes

The regular expressions `imagu\W?\s+[sk]e` and `supozu\W?\s+[sk]e` say this:

1. **`imagu`:** Search for `imagu` or `supozu`. (Technically, this should probably be `\bimagu` and `\bsupozu`—beginning with a word boundary `\b`—to avoid cases where these are just the ends of longer words, but it didn’t matter in this case.)
2. **`\W?`:** Once you’ve found that, look for a possible single non-word character—this is to allow for the possibility of a comma or other punctuation mark.
3. **`\s+`:** Then look for some space so you separate `imagu` or `supozu` or `imagu,`, etc., from the following word.
4. **`[sk]`:** Look for either an `s` or a `k`.
5. **`e`:** Finally, look for an `e` to make *se/ke.* (Again, it would technically be more correct to end with another `\b` to avoid cases where *se* or *ke* begin a word, but again, it doesn’t really matter here.)

Answer (score 0):

Ĉe mi oni kutime diras:

*Imagu nur, se mi ...*

Comment: Interese, sed ne ŝajnas al mi ke la “nur” solvus la problemon de la mallogika uzo de “se”. Se mi serĉas “imag\VF nur” en Tekstaro, aperas kelkaj ekzemploj de “imagu nur, ke”, sed neniu kun “se”.

Comment: Tiu _imagu nur; ..._ apartenas al la familia uzo.. Mi ne scias ĉu oni trovus tiun konstruaĵon ofte en Tekstaro. Ĝi (ĉe ni, familie) rolas kiel enkonduka subfrazo (komence) kaj iel kiel interjekcio, kiam ĝi troviĝas fine. Ekzemple _La intruistino volis lastsekunde aldoni temon al la ekzameno, imagu nur! Ni laŭte plendis_.

Answer (score -1):

A side note…

[*Gajni*](http://vortaro.net/#gajni) (← (en) to gain ← (old French) *gaaignier*) means to win, to get something, like **money** or  a **point**, in a game or in a competition.

> *gajni poento**n** aŭ premio**n** **en** la matĉo/konkurso*

I.e.

> *Imagu, ke mi gajnus en loterio.*

Note, that if you win **someone**, you use another verb, [*venki*](http://vortaro.net/#venki).

> *Julio Cezaro venkis la pontanojn kaj gajnis gloron.*

In neither case can you say *gajni/venki ludon*, because you aren't getting or winning the game itself. One might wonder how you say in games without any other opponent than the game itself.

> *solvi Kubon de Rubrik*
>
> *venki en paciencludo*

Comment: La 2-a difino de _[gajni](http://vortaro.net/#gajni)_ en PIV tekstas jene: _Superi la alian partion en ludbatalo: "gajni la ludon, la matĉon, la partion, la veton"_. Mi supozas, ke en _gajni la loterion_ oni subkomprenas _gajni la loteri-premion_ aŭ eĉ _gajni en la loterio_.

Comment: Vi pravas, ke PIV donas ankaŭ tiun difinon. Sed komparu ekz. kun Reta vortaro. Se vi serĉas inter tekstoj en Tekstaro.com, vi notas, ke tia uzo oftiĝas dum ĉi tiu jarcento, antaŭe la esprimo _gajni + ludo_ aperas nur malofte. Do eblas, ke la signifo ŝanĝiĝas ĝuste nun.

Comment: Dankon pro la sugesto sed mi malsuprenvoĉdonas ĉar ĝi ne respondas al la demando.